# Page and print preview do not match up visually

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an HTML page and when I view the page there are no margins because I set margins and padding to 0px; in my CSS.  The issue is when I go to print preview it shows with the margins from the browser setup.

Is there a way I can add margins to my page when viewing but that it doesn't add that extra margin space when it prints?  I end up with a pretty big margin.

Comment: CSS allows a seperate   **print** specification , will post you in a couple of moments.

Comment: Check this page, it explains how you set up the stylesheet for print, which sounds like what you need. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css `@media` and create different styles for when you want something to look/render differently when it's printed

```
.my__class {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media print {
    .my__class {
      font-size: 80px; // when you print .my__class will be 80px, but 20px on screen
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thank you for the example Darren.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of the basic rule:

```
  <style tyle="text/css">
  <!--
  @media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
  }

 @media screen {
  body { font-size: 12pt }
 }
 @media screen, print {
  body { line-height: 1.2 }
 }
 -->
 </style>
```